# Function to remove annotation in ggplot?

Tags: function, ggplot2, annotations

I've generated 2 plots using ggplot, and I've incorporated text annotations into each of them using the "annotate" function.
Now, I'm aggregating the plots in a single composite plot.
During this process, I've decided that I want to replace the existing annotations in each individual plot with new ones.
While I could certainly modify the original plots directly, I'm curious if there exists a dedicated "remove_annotation" function that would facilitate this task.
Thank you

Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)


set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(
  Group = rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), each = 5),
  Value = c(rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 1), rnorm(5, mean = 8, sd = 1))
)




plot1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())  +
  labs(title = "Group Comparison", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal() +
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = 1,
    y = 7,
    label = ifelse(p_value < 0.001, "p < 0.001", ""),
    size = 4,
    vjust = -0.5,
    hjust = 0.5
  )+theme(legend.position = "none")


plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())  +
  labs(title = "Group Comparison", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal() +
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = 1,
    y = 9,
    label = ifelse(p_value < 0.001, "p < 0.001", ""),
    size = 4,
    vjust = -0.5,
    hjust = 0.5
  )+theme(legend.position = "none")

library(gridExtra)

combined_plot <- grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 2)


print(combined_plot)
```

As you can see, the annotations are not on the same level. In this easy example, I could go back and remove the annotations directly in the plot, but I was wondering if you could create a "remove_annotation" function where a posteriori you can remove the text.

Comment: Can you just leave your annotations out in the original three plots, before you aggregate them? It will be easier to help you if you create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/16510400